# Is Continue in Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6, continue

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to replace a GoTo in a while loop with a Continue, but whenever I do I get an error reading "Statement expected, but expression of type 'Boolean' found".  Is continue a keyword not in Delphi 6? Does the error message mean something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in Delphi 5, so I would assume it is in Delphi 6. 
There must be something else going on in your code, but without posting it, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the code.  But I did look a bit harder and somebody named a boolean variable "continue" and that overrode the keyword continue...

Comment: @mnuzzo: I think that qualifies as "...something else going on in your code..." ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that somebody gave a variable the same name as the keyword and Delphi is using that instead of the keyword.  Find the variable and try renaming it.